# How should LocalDate be stored as a JSON property in a postgres jsonb column with Hibernate JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have a jsonb column in postgres table. The corresponding JPA entity field is a Java DTO with a LocalDate property. The LocalDate field is being stored in postgres as what appears to be a list.

The JAVA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbeddedId embeddedId;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "jsonb_column", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
    private JavaDto javaDto;
}
```

JavaDto.java:

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JavaDto
{
    private LocalDate localDate;
    private String type;
    private String id;
}
```

Sample row in `my_table` postgres table:

```
id                  | 90
other_col           | OTHER_COL_VAL
jsonb_column        | {"id": "123-some-id", "type": "someType", "localDate": [2021, 10, 13]}
creation_time       | 2020-11-02 15:44:42.134+05:30
last_modified_time  | 2020-11-02 15:44:42.134+05:30
```

The format in which localDate is getting stored is creating issues to run read queries with where clause.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Hibernate as the JPA implementation.

Comment: Do you have any registered converter for the type: @Type(type = "jsonb") ?

Comment: I haven't defined any converter explicitly.

Comment: Does your project have `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52` dependency?

Comment: yes, can that help in some way? I haven't checked that.

Comment: just checked, the artifact id is hibernate-types-43 (not 52).

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats used by default in *java.time*.